# Splitting a String?

Tags: apex, string

```
General Information Requested &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Sample&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;                                      Priority                                    Low                                     Issue Description                       Working                                     Issue Type                      Change                                                  Module                                  english                                     Reported By                     1234                                        Submitted By                        8433                                        Date submited                       12/04/2016
```

I need to split the sting below showing list format

```
 General Information Requested
Sample           

Priority

Low

Issue Description

Working

Issue Type

Change

Module

english

Reported By

1234

Submitted By

8433

Date submited

12/04/2016
```

I am trying to get the result but not getting it. How can I split the string properly?

Answer (score 4):

You can split on a regular expression. In this case, you want to split on any instance of two or more whitespace or `&nbsp` characters.

```
String input = 'General Information Requested &nbsp;...';
List<String> lines = input.split('(\\s|&nbsp;){2,}');
```

Components of the above expression:

- `(...){N,}` - Match `N` or more consecutive matches against the expression inside the parentheses `(...)`.
- `A|B` - Match expression `A` *or* expression `B`.
- `\\s` - Ends up as the expression `\s`, which matches any whitespace character.
- `&nbsp;` - Matches the literal string for a non-breaking space character.

Answer (score 1):

In this example I am using ; you can change that to whatever you are using to separate your string values.

```
string example = 'one;two;three';
List<String> list = new List<String>();
for(String s : example.split(';'))
{
   list.add(s);
}
```

Comment: No need for the loop

Comment: I provided an example where he could figure out the logic for his case. I know the loop is not needed but for someone who is starting it makes more sense. I am just trying to help here. He can always mark your answer as correct and if you don't like mine... go ahead and delete it.